# Why I am getting Kestrel binding permission denied error over port 443 while container running as non root user

Tags: docker, https, .net-6.0, kestrel-http-server

I am running .Net 6 api app as a non-root user and trying to set ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT = 443.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine AS final
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443

RUN adduser --disabled-password --home /app --gecos '' nonroot && chown -R nonroot /app
USER nonroot
```

While container is running I am getting Kestrel binding permission denied error, why I am getting this error?

> Unhandled exception. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (13): Permission denied
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportOptions.CreateDefaultBoundListenSocket(EndPoint endpoint)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig endpointConfig, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`1.<g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()

I am seeing while I am setting ports other than 443, then it's working. (`ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5080    ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5080`)

Comment: What version of Docker are you running on? On 'normal' Linux, ports below 1024 are privileged and you need to be root to use them. But at some point, non-root users were allowed to use them in Docker.

Comment: I an running over Azure Kubernetes Services and using Kubernetes version 1.24 using containerd

Comment: how to root the port below 1024

Comment: Why not just use a port above 1024?